# Angular2 shared service to observe resolver in route guard canActivate

Tags: angular, router, roles, guard, resolver

Let's assume I got a route using a canActivate-Guard. The route's path only consists of one param :xyzType. Inside the data object of the route I specified an array of required permissions for each possible :xyzType.

```
{
    path: ':xyzType',
    component: SuperSpecialComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {
      permissions: {
        "type1": [
          "add:type1", "edit:type1"
        ],
        "type2": [
          "add:type2", "edit:type2"
        ]
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      permissions: PermissionsResolver
    }
  }
```

The PermissionResolver checks which value the :xyzType parameter got and returns route.data['permissions'][:xyzType-value].

So for example if '/type1' is called in the browser the PermissionResolver returns

```
["add:type1", "edit:type1"]
```

Am I right assuming that route.data['permissions'] would match that returned array as well??!

So the problem is that the AuthGuard is fired before the PermissionResolver has done what it should do.

I did not manage to get to work a service (shared between PermissionResolver and AuthGuard) which kind of observes the PermissionResolver 'until its finished' respectively observes the route.data.permissions to get a new value, so that AuthGuard only runs after PermissionResolver is done.

Any help or ideas on this?
Its quite hard to find anything more special than just super simple examples on angular2 roles and permissions out there.

Thanks =)